# generator-angular-fullstack No Bower components found

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am new in yo generators and I am being experimented on many of them. I set up an angular scaffold with no problems and I tried to do the same by setting up an angular-fullstack scaffold to test MEAN. Unfortunately I wasn't so lucky as I was with angular and I got the error message 'No Bower components found'. Besides I had the .bowerrc file, the generator was unable to create the relevant folder.

I was trying to figure it out what is happening and what caused that issue. All of a sudden I realized that when setting up the app in c:\folderOne\folderTwo was working in contrary of c:\folderOne\folderTwo\folderThree where didn't. So I did the assumption that something is happening with the length of the path and in the same time I had a thought that something is happening with the filesystem levels.

I made many many different 'installations' in different environments and the behavior was different from each other. So, there isn't a level problem nor length issue.

Does anyone had a similar problem with that? What can I do for having a stability?

my system have the following characteristics

```
node: '0.10.25'
npm: '1.3.24'
yo: '1.1.2'
os: win7
```

**those are the steps I followed**

```
yo angular-fullstack
 _-----_
|       |
|--(o)--|   .--------------------------.
`---------´  |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
( _´U`_ )   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
/___A___\   '__________________________'
 |  ~  |
__'.___.'__
´   `  |° ´ Y `

Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

[?] Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? (Y/n) n
[?] Would you like to include Twitter Bootstrap? (Y/n) y
[?] Which modules would you like to include?
[ ] angular-resource.js
[ ] angular-cookies.js
[ ] angular-sanitize.js
>[ ] angular-route.js
[?] Would you like to include MongoDB with Mongoose? (y/N) n
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `bower install` in the project root.

Comment: thanks for your reply, however if you noticed in my post I mention that there was some times that everything worked just fine (this means that bower install could work as well) an there was sometimes (still i don't know the reason) that I couldn't install the bower componenets although I had the .bowerrc file. In the time of speaking I had done a great progress over yo-generators apps and to be honest I had forgotten this post :). Apart from the aforementioned, I will accept your answer as in many cases this might be the solution

Comment: how were you able to solve this issue i tried with bower install also and all the packages are currently present in my bower_components?

Comment: try removing `bower_components` and re-installing